# country code will automatically added before mobile number

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

If any one type in input box only number like : `01234567890` (total 13 digit with country code) then automatically add `88` before mobile number but if if anyone number with `8801234567890` it wont added before number. Another one if type `1234567890` total 10 digit then add `880` before number. how to fix it? I tried with add value but its not working. I need only my conditions not every time.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#phone').keyup(function() {
        let total_length = this.value.length;
        
        if(total_length='11'){
          $("#phone").val("88"+$("#phone").val());
        }
        else if(total_length='10'){
          $("#phone").val("880"+$("#phone").val());
        }
        else{
           $("#phone").val();
        }
    });

    $.validator.addMethod("countryValid", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^(?:\+88|88)?(01[3-9]\d{8})$/i.test(value);
      }, "Please enter valid phone no."); 

  
    $("#my_form").validate({
        rules: {
        phone : {
            required: true,
            number: true,
            countryValid: true
        }
        }
    });

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="my_form">

<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />
<br><br>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: `=` is assignment. Comparison for equality is `==`. This is your issue.

Comment: Also, you should better react on `input` and not `keyup`. What if I put something in without using my keyboard (for instance autofill, right-click -> paste or drag & drop)?

Comment: it will also work if i put 10 digit it will add 880 but if if put 11 digit it will add 88 only.. now my code okay but when it found 10 digit on keyup it auto added without writing 11digit..

Comment: maybe you want to react on `change` then and not `keyup`/`input`? (so only once the user leaves the field it will trigger)

Comment: yes it fixed now thanks i forgot to add change function instead of keyup Thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with replace `keyup` to `change` and add the `==`(Equal to) from `=`(assignment operators)

```
$('#phone').change(function() {
        let total_length = this.value.length;
        
        if(total_length=='11'){
          $("#phone").val("88"+$("#phone").val());
        }
        else if(total_length=='10'){
          $("#phone").val("880"+$("#phone").val());
        }
        else{
           $("#phone").val();
        }
    });
```

Thanks @[CherryDT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1871033/cherrydt) for this help.